# Can SESSION variables be slow to set or unset?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i was just wondering if a SESSION variable can be sometimes slow to set/unset?

To be honest I'm not sure how to test exactly how quick a SESSION becomes set or unset but i have noticed when i use an ajax call to set/unset a SESSION variable about 10% of the time the code in the ajax callback function executes before the SESSION variable is set/unset.

I have put a setTimeout in the callback function to have it wait a second before it executes to code and this seems eliminate the problem, though it kind of seems like a bad fix. Is it considered bad practice to do something like that?

Learner here, be kind :-)

**jQuery**

```
$("#whatever_button").click(function(){  

    var $x = "1";

    $.ajax({      
        url: "filename.php",
        data: { set_session: $x},
        type: "post",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response){
            if (response == "1"){

               //delay execution for 1 second
               setTimeout(function(){
                   //Place code here
               }, 1000);

            } else alert("Something went wrong.");
        },
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['set_session'])){

    unset($_SESSION['variable']);    //unset session variable
    echo "1";
}
```

Comment: did you start a session? what is actual response in body of request? Using setTimeout inside success and inside the test for valid response doesn't really make sense. You've already got that valid respons when you start the timer

Comment: How are you telling whether the session variable is set or unset?

Comment: I can tell the session has been set or unset because when i manually refresh the page with the browser the variable then shows set/unset as i wanted

Comment: @charlietfl, the call back function executes before the SESSION variable is set. So i delay the execution of the code so the SESSION variable can catch up

Comment: I suspect there is something else wrong. What are you needing to delay a redirect? Or another ajax call?

Comment: To delay the refresh of the page, i was using ajax so it didn't have to PRG that form submissions present. Also the reload.loaction() seemed more useful the form submit because the page can be reloaded as many times as neededwithout it creating a page history, the user can click the back button in the browser and return to the previous page no matter how many times the page has been reloaded. Maybe i'm doing it wrong

Comment: @charlietfl can you have a look on his comment below my answer? Can this really need 2 seconds?

Comment: @michael 85 floppy...hampster driven power supply?

Comment: @ charlietfl Hahaha! The laptop i have is a cheapy, though not even 12 months old. Acer E5- 521. So i am gathering this is something i am only experiencing on my end? i am using localhost at the moment

Comment: @charlietfl good one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session is stored in a file, so depending on your server it can take some milliseconds to save it, though I would hardly doubt that this will ever be noticeable unless you have set your session_save_path to a 1985' floppy drive with a barely working floppy in it.

More interesting is the purpose you are aiming for, as you don't return anything related to the newly unset `$_SESSION['variable']`.

Maybe you should include a test to see if the session is unset

```
unset($_SESSION['variable']);
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['variable'])) return '1';
```

If you want to check times, you can allways make use of php's `microtime()` function.

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
unset($_SESSION['variable']);
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "$time seconds";
```

Comment: I was using it to unset a user_name variable and then refresh the page, though when the page was refreshed 1 out of 10 times it would still show the user as logged in, then i have to manually refresh the browser so it shows the user logged out(as the session is unset). i will try and check the times :-)

Comment: Why using ajax when you refresh the page afterwards??? Get rid of ajax and reload the page normally

Comment: Well i was using ajax so there was no PRG with form submissions and using location.reload() doesn't create a page history so the user can return to the previous page no matter how many times the page is reloaded. I guess i'm doing it very wrong.

Comment: here is a list of 11 consecutive times, notice that some are exactly the same time? 1.6927719116211E-5 seconds
2.0027160644531E-5 seconds
1.9073486328125E-5 seconds
2.0980834960938E-5 seconds
2.0027160644531E-5 seconds
1.7881393432617E-5 seconds
1.5020370483398E-5 seconds
2.1934509277344E-5 seconds
1.5974044799805E-5 seconds
1.8119812011719E-5 seconds
1.6927719116211E-5 seconds

Comment: @user3796133 what did you use to convert to seconds? microtime() actually returns `microseconds` so michael i think made a slip up using the word seconds without converting

Comment: well it's 2AM for me but by my fuzzy math you need to divide by a million  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond

Comment: I thought this too, but it's a nearly one to one copy from php's microtime documentation.http://php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php

Comment: try using `time()` that for sure is seconds. I see the phph manual version too...strange to me

Comment: I will test on another computer

Comment: it must be microseconds, i temporarliy uploaded the page to a hosted server and tried on a different comp. some are 4 "seconds" though it didn't take 4 seconds to return that response so it must be microseconds. I will try time() too . 8.10623168945E-6 seconds
3.09944152832E-6 seconds
2.86102294922E-6 seconds
3.09944152832E-6 seconds
2.86102294922E-6 seconds
3.09944152832E-6 seconds
3.09944152832E-6 seconds
4.05311584473E-6 seconds

Comment: time() returns 0 seconds every time.